# How would I achieve this animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How would I achieve the following animation in Flutter?

[Video demonstration](https://www.veed.io/view/c553bc17-d838-4de4-9277-ce456b6aea30?sharingWidget=true)

Answer (score 1):

This look like an Hero (In Flutter)... for dispose the storie, you can use the Draggable widget, with **draaggable details** you will determine if is okay to dispose or not.